# Cross domain PHP session authorized API requests with Axios

Tags: javascript, php, api, asynchronous, vue.js

I am working on a Vue js project which uses an API build in PHP from another domain. API-calls are done with AXIOS.

When i log in via the API i get get back my PHPSESSID. This cookie is not stored in the browser and i cannot access the value in the response. I need this PHPSESSID value to send with future-requests and get related data, stay logged in etc..

```
axios.create({
    withCredentials: true,
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
```

The response header contains:
`Set-Cookie 
PHPSESSID=6amji3ps4tdnkhflbd8depjas0; path=/`

Can someone, point me in the right way please?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can look at this [repo](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors), it allow you to expose headers (CORS problems), you just have to add the set cookie header and then parse the value using regex.

Comment: The session cookie is probably `httpOnly` and those are protected from javascript access. Only the browser can access them when sending receiving

Comment: @charlietfl, Can the httpOnly be set to false so js can access the session-cookie?

Comment: Not locally. Sounds like you might need to use a proxy if you don't control the remote api

Comment: I do control the API, so far no luck with setting cookie-params, any pointers?

Comment: When the API is on another domain, `same-origin` does not apply, does it? Try `credentials: 'include'`, that has worked for me before using `fetch` (never used Axios, sorry). Also, I don't think `httpOnly` is a problem, as it only prevents JS from accessing the Cookie. It should however be included in requests instrumented by JS.

Comment: @TobiasK, unfortunately this does not work. httpOnly is false by the way and i am not able to access the set-cookie header.

Comment: @TobiasK, good point by the way about the same-origin!

Comment: This is supposed to happen automatically. I'm getting a strange scenario where on one machine it works but on another it doesn't.